# DynamoDB wrapper for Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

What is the best npm library for dynamodb? There are quite a few on npm.

Right now my production application is running with a mongodb and mongoose.

Comment: Are you using dynamodb through AWS SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of good ones:

[vogels](https://github.com/ryanfitz/vogels) and 
[dynamite](https://github.com/Medium/dynamite)

I'm using Vogels in my app at the moment, I like that it gives an extra layer of protection over your database via a Joi Schema, though it's not maintained as actively as you might like.

Dynamite is promise based and built by Medium, so it's worth a look as well.

Answer (score 6):

Now things are becoming simple in Dynamodb using schema based **AWS dynamodb data mapper library in Node.js**
For more details, have a look on following aws package.

[Data Mapper with annotation](https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations/)

[Data Mapper package for Javascript](https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/)

Advantages of using Amazon Data mapper library

1. Library take cares of Data marshaling
2. Schemas will be mapped to Javascript class entities
3. Similar to ORM
4. Developed by Amazon